# Communication between view and controller in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Imagine I have a form (Page1.cshtml) with 1 link (LinkBrands). I also have a controller for Page1 (Page1Controller) and one for brands (BrandController). When the user clicks the link what is better to do:

1. LinkBrands-->Page1Controller-->BrandController (Page1Controller's action will redirect to BrandController)

OR

1. LinkBrands-->BrandController

Not sure what route is better. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't have a single controller per view. You would use multiple views or partial views all calling actions on the same related controller. I assume Brand is a separate entity from whatever else Page1 is trying to display, therefore it should probably use the BrandController directly but since there really isn't enough information to go on with your example as to what page1's function is I couldn't say what you are trying to relate.

If you need to capture information from the brand link as it relates to page1 then sure have it collect that in page1controller first before redirecting to brandcontroller to display a new view.

Comment: Page1 is displaying a welcome message and a link named LinkBrands.
Yes Brand is a separate entity. Clicking the LinkBrands will display all brands on a new page (view).

Answer (score 0):

It all depends.

If you have to execute any logic in Page1Controller (saving data for instance) before displaying the second page, then you need to go by Page1Controller, and then go to BrandController:

```
LinkBrands-->Page1Controller-->BrandController
```

In case you just need to redirected to the second page (you do not need anything from Page1Controller, you do not need it to perform any action, and you can create a the model for second page in BrandController) then go with the second option:

```
LinkBrands-->BrandController
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks that helps a little; however, I am still a little confused. I guess benjamin above has a point: "Usually you don't have a single controller per view."

Comment: For sure, but that is linked to your goals and design. If Page1Controller and BrandController belong to different processes/domains, each controlling its own set of views and feeding from different model, then it is natural they are separated controllers. If the case is the opposite, they are some how related because of process/domain then maybe there should only be one controller with multiple views. For example, I once had a registration process with many steps: each step was a different view, but a single controller controling the submit of the info and the view to display in the next step.

Answer (score 0):

What does your `Page1Controller` do??  It seems as though you are defeating the purpose of the Model-View-Controller architecture and trying to form it back to the WebForms method with code-behind.

So without seeing what exactly your controllers are doing, I'd say your second option is best.

Comment: What Page1Controller does will be based on the answer to my question. I am not sure whether it should handle the request or the request should be handled directly by BrandController.

First approach SEEMS better because all the requests for the page are handled by one controller. The controller will decide if the the request should be redirected to another controller. What do you think?